# QGIS - error connection of database in RiverGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Currently, I am facing a problem to connect Postgres database to RiverGIS. It shows this error.

```
Couldn't connect to river database: rivergis@localhost
Please, check you database connection settings!
```

But, I checked the connection in the PostgresSQL, and it says the connection is successful.

[image: Rivergis error]

[image: postgresSQL connection checking (successfully connected)]

[image: DB manager connection (not connected)]

Comment: Please open the rivesgis database in DB Manager by double clicking on the name of the databsae or by clicking on the triangle in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same aforementioned problem with the Rivergis plugin.*

In order to resolve the problem, you should click on two "store" buttons in
the Basic Tab. After that, click Ok for the new question.